# How can I control the Hex-Rays decompiler plugin from IDA with scripts?

Tags: ida, ida-plugin, idapython

I want to use IDA with the Hex-Rays decompiler plugin as part of automated static analysis, possibly on a large number of files without opening each one and telling it to produce a C file individually.

Ideally, I'd like to run IDA from the command line, and get the decompilation based on initial autoanalysis as output.  This way I can run it as part of [Mastiff](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mastiff/) or grep for certain functions in a set of binaries.   By my reading of [On batch analysis](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=53) from the Hex Blog, what I need is an IDA script that interacts with the decompiler plugin, but I can't figure out how to actually do so.

So this leaves me with 2 subquestions:

- How can I tell the Hex-Rays decompiler to "Produce C file" (decompile all functions) from a script?
- Does that script need to be IDC, or is IDAPython possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Back in 2013] the decompiler did not have a scripting API. So you had these choices:

- [Add necessary functions to IDC](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=126) using a native plugin that calls the decompiler API.
- Use `ctypes` or similar to call the C++ API directly from Python. I posted a small PoC script doing it to the Hex-Rays forum a couple years ago.
- If you just want to have the decompiled text, you can use [the command line option](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/batch.shtml).

[IDA 6.6 (released in June 2014)](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/6.6/index.shtml) added official Python bindings for the decompiler, so it now can be scripted from Python. For sample code, see `vds*.py` scripts in the [IDAPython repository](https://github.com/idapython/src/tree/master/examples).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93139/discussion-on-answer-by-igor-skochinsky-how-can-i-control-the-hex-rays-decompile).